# How to produce spectral signature using SCP plugin for drone images

Tags: qgis, remote-sensing, unmanned-aerial-vehicle, scp, dji

The SCP plugin can output spectral signatures of satellite remote sensing imagery. I'm wondering, has anyone tried to use the SCP plugin to output spectral signatures of drone-based imagery (for my case a DJI Phantom 4 multispectral drone)? And how did you go about this?